# Using distributed transaction for a single wcf service method call

Tags: .net, wcf, distributed-transactions, msdtc

I implement a WCF payment service with methods like `Deposit(amount)` and `Withdraw(amount)`. I want to garantee that payment transaction will not be performed if a service method call throws an exception on the client-side (in case of network-related problems leading to the lost or corrupted response).

Should service clients spawn a distributed transaction just to make single method call? Or there is a better approach?

Comment: Are your clients wcf and on the same network?

Comment: @TomRedfern Most of our clients will be from intranet, but external clients should also be supported.

Answer (score 0):

With netTcpBinding, supporting DTC transactions accross the network is [fairly trivial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thelever/archive/2007/02/27/transaction-flow-in-wcf.aspx). Your clients won't even be aware that they're propagating a transaction for the service to enlist in as the WCF stack hides all this.

Doing it across the internet however is a huge difference, and you will be forced to expose your service across HTTPS and configure WS-Atomic Transaction support on your endpoints.

If you can avoid exposing the endpoint on the internet then that would be easier.

A better solution IMO than this would be to provide a non-transactional endpoint for Deposits and then a separate service where the client can request the deposit they just made.

Then the client can just call the Deposit operation again if they can't find their deposit. To support this model you would need to make sure your service could not process the same deposit more than once.

A further alternative (though more elaborate) is you expose a "callback service" on the client which the service can call with a acknowledgement. The minimum number of one way calls you require to guarantee delivery in this manner is 3:

1. Client calls service with deposit. If it doesn't receive an acknowledgement within x then it calls again.
2. Service receives deposit and then sends acknowledgement via callback to the client. If it doesn't receive confirmation of ack within x it send again.
3. Client receives ack and then sends confirmation.

Comment: All clients (both from intranet and internet) of the payment service are well-known, e.g. service and its clients can be configured to run distributed transaction.

Comment: The main question is - are distributed transactions is an appropriate direction to solve my problem? I didn’t googled any examples of using a distributed transaction for a single service method call. At the same time I want to avoid reinventing the will by rolling out my own solution.

Comment: It rather difficult to correctly implement two-phase commit protocol because proper implementation of the CommitRequest phase issues PrepareCommits on database level instead of simple Commits.  In your example on step 2 the service commits changes to the database, so concurrent transactions will assume this transaction completed regardless potential connectivity failures on service response delivery. To avoid this situation custom transaction statuses should be introduces, so the solution become more complicated and error-prone.

Comment: Did you read the part of my answer where I said another way of doing it is to allow clients to check their deposit had been committed via a second service call? That would appear to be another option to avoid using transactions. I agree with your last statement that it is more complex.

Comment: I don't understand on which step number you propose to commit transaction to database.

Comment: What I'm saying is don't even use transactions. You can acheive consistency without them

Answer (score 0):

When having external clients, they probably can not access the DTC server. So making one call and handling the transaction on the server would be recommended in this case.

Comment: What if the client made the call and the response timed out. Did the transaction commit or not? Should the client call again? Also, what if the client received the response from the call but then something went  wrong on the service end after the client channel disconnects. How will the client know that the call was successful?

Comment: Assuming that every transaction processing takes 5-10 seconds and one network drop per day is expected, there is a high probability to receive at least one "undetermined" transaction per day.

Comment: @Nuf-Nuf I can't think of any reason why the client has to be in charge of the transaction. Code running on a client should not be trusted at any time, a transaction will only guarantee that the question it has asked is performed as one or not at all. Any logic which is one action in the concept of an user should be handled on the server,  which should also handle the transaction. If the client loses its connection it can just query the server if the transaction succeeded.

Comment: @peer Payment action should be performed transactionally **from the client's (not server!) perspective**. When you push Withdraw button on ATM and then see “network error” message on the screen, you want to be sure your balance didn’t change, right? Or you’ll be just happy to know that something that occurred on the server conformed to ACID properties?  If the client loses its connection it can't just query the server because the connection is lost. So the idea is to find an appropriate way to minimise the probability of undetermined service call results.

Comment: An atm does not use transaction the way you describing, it does use a recovery to check and correct errors at a later time. Putting a withdraw and a deposit in one transaction on a client will also limit the number of transactions and have serious consequences for the number of concurrent users. A money trans fare should never have any 'money token value' on a client if it happens on a bank. If the money goes from one bank to a other the bank should handle the trans fare logic, not the client. That is why you are using the bank in the first place.